# Which variables are thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, thread-safety, scope

I am having a Servlet A which defines a local variable say `a1` in one of its method as shown below. There is another class B for which object is created in Servlet A and that object calls the method and do operation.

Which one of these variable `a1` and `a2` is thread safe and why? I believe that `a1` is thread safe since that is local to class A and `a2` is not thread safe since that is behaving as a member variable.

```
class Servlet A {    
    public void method1(){
        String a1;    
        B b = new b();
        String c = b.method2(a1);    
    }  
}

class B {
    String a2;
    public String method2(String a1){
        // do operations on a1 and a2 
        return a1+a2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are right. Method-scoped variables (local variables) are thread safe, because they live on stack and couldn't be accessed by other threads.

Member variables (fields) live on heap and are not thread-safe, because they could be accessed simultaneously by multiple threads.

Comment: @Thanks Denis... so can you confirm in my case a1 is thread safe and a2 is not ?

Comment: Will a1 here is a local variable or member variable ? since i am using a1 in another class B so will it be treated as member variable ?

Comment: No, it won't. *a1* is a local variable to A::method1. *a1* is a local variable to B::method2. But those are two completely different variables, each local to its own method. When you invoke *b.method2(a1)*, local variable A::method1::a1 is copied (not exactly, but think of it as copying) to local variable B::method2::a1.

Comment: Thanks Denis..you made it very clear..Thanks...one last question. As you know as of now a2 is defined outside the method in class B , so i think as of now it is not thread safe ? What is i declare a2 inside method2 , will it be treated as member variable still ? Or will it be treated as local variable then and become thread safe ?

Comment: If you declare it inside *method2* it will become local and thus thread-safe, but you'll be able to access it only inside *method2* then. Member variables could be accessed by multiple methods, which makes them extremelly useful for saving state across methods.

Comment: In this specific implementation both variables are thread safe, since  they are both local variables for the method. Thread safety implies having a shared state, which there is no in this sample. Class B can potentially be used as non thread safe shared object, but this is a different story, which does not apply to this example.